# Why does having a ReadableStream body trigger a CORS preflight request?

Tags: http, cors, preflight

The logic in the fetch spec behind whether a browser request needs a preflight is based on whether it is "simple". For example, setting custom headers is not simple and requires a preflight. My understanding is that this is mostly about ensuring that the request is likely to be "getting a resource" and not "executing an API".

One of the conditions is that the body is not a ReadableStream. Why does that matter? From a security perspective, I can imagine "anything with a body at all should be preflighted" making sense, but that's not the logic: it's "strings are OK, ReadableStreams are not".

Comment: See https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/88#issue-96682235 and https://github.com/yutakahirano/fetch-with-streams/issues/10, which started out with the question, *“Since this allows inspection of how fast a body is transmitted to the server, should this require a preflight just like we do in XMLHttpRequest for progress events?”* (and the answer for which ended up being *Yes*).

Answer (score 4):

The issue at hand, as @sideshowbarker alludes to in his comment, is whether the server is equipped to handle `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, which is automatically sent for `ReadableStream` bodies. (Since we don't know their length ahead of time.)

Before `ReadableStream` fetches, it was not possible to send a cross-origin `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` request. E.g., there's no way to do that with `<form>`. So this represents a new thing that browsers could do to unsuspecting servers, including to intranet servers. Thus, the preflight: the server has to say "yes, I am OK with getting requests from that origin, and am prepared for the consequences".